# Firefox Add ON - To Check for Absolute and Relative Links

Tags: firefox-addon

Does anyone know if there is some type of tool, preferably a Firefox add on that can check the links on a page if they are absolute links (going to another website) or relative links (within the website)...

I have searched on Google, and the Firefox add ons and haven't seen any. How  hard would it be to make my own? What do you guys suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you checkout [ExNewT](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10499) ?

btw, it is not that hard to search on addons.mozilla.org, you should have do it yourself.

Comment: nope. couldn't find one, I've searched everywhere on Google. trust me.

Comment: Why don't you follow the link?

Comment: ExNewT is not available for Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Write your own Javascript to go through all the elements in the document, or maybe there is a better way to access links using a [Mozilla class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074961/where-are-the-docs-for-creating-firefox-addons/1077740#1077740), and use [this guide](http://www.webreference.com/html/tutorial2/3.html) to discern between absolute and relative links.